# how to get one or more rows from the table using queryForObject with rowMapper?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

What I am tring to do is to select the username, password, and role from studentstable using queryForObject.

In my JdbcTemplate syntax is

```
public static Object queryForObject(String sql,RowMAPPER mapper,Object ...args)
```

The problem is here in my JdbcStudentDAO

```
public class JdbcStudentDAO implements StudentDAO{
    public String getLogin(StudentTO sto) {

        String sql="select username,password,role from studentstable";
        System.out.println(sql);
```

Here I don't know what is wrong below

```
        Object obj=JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new StudentRowMapper(),sto.getUsername(),sto.getPassword(),sto.getRole());
        StudentTO sto1=(StudentTO)obj;
        System.out.println(sto1);


    return sto1.toString();
}
}
```

This is my RowMapper where I'm getting all rows of my database, as shown below

```
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper{

    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        StudentTO sto=new StudentTO();

        sto.setSid(rs.getInt(1));
        sto.setName(rs.getString(2));
        sto.setUsername(rs.getString(3));
        sto.setPassword(rs.getString(4));
        sto.setEmail(rs.getString(5));
        sto.setPhone(rs.getLong(6));
        sto.setRole(rs.getString(7));
        return sto;
    }


}
```

This is an abstract method in StudentDAO

```
public interface StudentDAO {


    public String getLogin(StudentTO sto);


}
```

Comment: it will be a great if some body tell me how to retrieve only 3 particular columns out of 7

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?

Comment: getInt is not of type username

Comment: Change your query to this `String sql="select * from studentstable";`

Answer (score 0):

This is your query

```
select username,password,role from studentstable
```

You only have 3 columns, and they are not in the order defined by your extraction...

> ```
>     sto.setSid(rs.getInt(1));
>     sto.setName(rs.getString(2));
>     sto.setUsername(rs.getString(3));  // This is actually index 1
>     sto.setPassword(rs.getString(4));  // This is actually index 2
>     sto.setEmail(rs.getString(5));
>     sto.setPhone(rs.getLong(6));
>     sto.setRole(rs.getString(7));     // This is actually index 3
> ```

Therefore, you would need this

```
    sto.setUsername(rs.getString(1)); 
    sto.setPassword(rs.getString(2)); 
    sto.setRole(rs.getString(3));
```

And the other properties are the defaults

Comment: can you explain ur answ